# Cheeriojs returns nothing but document.getElementsByClassName does

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

I have a list of urls to scrape looking for an 'a' tag with the following two classes, industry-name and industry-link.  I want to grab the innerHtml and also the href.  I grab it in the console but I am having some trouble with Cheeriojs.

```
<a href="xxxxxxx" class="industry-name industry-link">Retail</a> // taken from target page
document.getElementsByClassName('industry-name industry-link')[0].innerHTML //runs in console and works as expected
document.getElementsByClassName('industry-name industry-link')[0].href //runs in console and works as expected

const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const got = require('got');

const url= 'xxxxxxx';

got(url).then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

    $('a', '.industry-name', '.industry-link').text();

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to puppeteer and that is working correctly.